# Getting information about deployment from within an instance of AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb, aws-cli

My specific need is to get the list of EC2 instances in the deployment from within one of the instances.

I've tried using AWS command line for example `aws elb describe-load-balancers` however it would just give details of all my AWS services. I know you can specify an instances name with `--load-balancer-name` but I just don't have access to that from within the instance automatically.

Perhaps a file can be created on instance creation by placing something in `.ebextensions`?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in a two step process using the AWS CLI.

First you get the endpoint for your Elastic Beanstalk application:

```
aws elasticbeanstalk describe-environments --query='Environments[?ApplicationName==`Your-application-name`].EndpointURL'
```

Then you use the endpoint to get the instances:

```
aws elb describe-load-balancers --query='LoadBalancerDescriptions[?DNSName==`load-balancer-end-point-from-previous-step`].Instances[0]'
```